# Display dictionary element with '#' in the key using django template tag

Tags: python, django, last.fm

I am trying to use the last.fm API, and the artist search returns the following dictionary with an image:

```
{u'#text': u'http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/79694767.png', u'size': u'small'}
```

However, in my django template, I can't seem to access the value in "#text".

I'm guessing it has to do with the '#' in the name:

My code:

```
{% for artist in results %}
    <li>
    {{artist.name}}
    {{artist.image.0.#text}}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you use standard dictionary notation? `{{artist.image.0['#text']}}`

Answer (score 0):

try this, # shouldnot be the problem:

```
{% for key, value in results.items %} 
 {{key}} - {{value}}
{% endfor %}
```